# DNS: How do I know what subdomains are registered to my server?

Tags: domain-name-system, unix

I have a website 'example.com', with the subdomain 'sub.example.com'. However, my clients are accessing the subdomain like this: 'www.sub.example.com'. Why this was an issue was 'www.sub' was redirecting to my main site, not my sub site.

My question is, how can I find out my dns records if my server is not the nameserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually i think there are two separate things:

- dns records - those you need to check with your dns hoster [ just run dns query for sub.example.com and see where do the name servers ; who do you pay for dns? that's the entity you should talk with. you can also get some hints by using http://dns.squish.net to lookup sub.example.com ]. it's very possible that there's wildcard configuration and anything.example.com points to the same server.
- web server vhosts configuration - you need to inspect what domain names are handle / served

Comment: You also should be able to use straightforward name lookup commands - `dig` or `nslookup` - they belong to package `dnsutils` on most linux distros. With that you establish the canonic names, their aliases and IP address(es) the names resolve to. Then what remains is webserver - it can take any name and basically redirect to any other. So it could serve a virtual host name1.ex.com and map name2.ex.com to be redirected to the first one.

Answer (score 3):

Ask the people who run your DNS for you.  Most companies that do this have a web interface where they will list all the records and allow you to change them.

You will probably find that you have a wildcard set up, so that a lookup for *any* subdomain will end up with the IP address of your server.